# Swagger - Render response status for declared exception

Tags: java, rest, swagger, http-status-codes, spring-restcontroller

I'm doing my REST documentation with swagger. I've set it up and got access on SwaggerUi and also see all my configured REST resources with their supported methods.

In my backend I have a `ControllerAdvice`, which does a global exception handling for all my controllers. A example exception which gets handled in the controller advice is `ResourceAlreadyExistsException`, when I try to create a resource which already exists, obviously. In that case my exception handler responds with a `409 CONFLICT` status code.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = ResourceAlreadyExistsException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
protected ErrorResponse handleResourceAlreadyExists(ResourceAlreadyExistsException ex, WebRequest request) {
    return new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage());
}
```

With this pre-condition, my create method which is mapped in the REST controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public RoleDto createRole(@RequestBody RoleDto roleDto) throws ResourceAlreadyExistsException {
    return roleManager.createRole(roleDto);
}
```

With the default configuration, Swagger only shows me 201 as possible response code. Although 409 is possible too.

Of course I could add the `@ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Role already exists")` definition to the `createRole()` method, but this seems double information as I already imply that by throwing the exception.

**How can I tell swagger, that if a `ResourceAlreadyExistsException` can be be thrown, 409 is also a possible response code?**

I've tried defining `@ApiResponse` on the `ResourceAlreadyExistsException`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Herr Derb Role Entity is marked as Unique (roleName)? because hibernate doesn't know Role is already existed or not without giving a unique constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature does not exist yet in SpringFox, although they have been looking for someone to implement it for quite some time now.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/521

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. Maybe I'd find time once in a while and try that. This would make life so much easier .